# Volleyのリクエストが行われない｡

Tags: android, android-volley

Activity上でVolleyのリクエストをしたのですが､リクエストが実行されていないようです｡  具体的には､`response`をLog出力したのですが､表示されません｡また､`error`も表示されないので､リクエスト自体が行われていないのだと思います｡

以下に､問題のリクエストを行うActivityを示します｡

**VideoPlayerActivity:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
    VideoInfoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
private String apiKey;
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment player;
private String videoId;
private List<String> relateVideoIds;

//フラグメントに送るデータ
private VideoItems videoInfo;
private ChannelSearchItems channelInfo;
private List<VideoItems> relateVideoItems;

//プログレスバーを保持
private LinearLayout progressLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    progressLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
    progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //リストを初期化
    relateVideoIds = new ArrayList<>();
    relateVideoItems = new ArrayList<>();

    //videoIdを取得
    Intent data = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    videoId = extras !=null ? extras.getString(VIDEO_ID) : "";

    //情報を取得
    relateVideoSearch();
    videoRequest();
    channelRequest();

    //mQueue,apiKeyを取得
    mQueue = RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    apiKey = DeveloperKey.API_KEY;

    //プレイヤを読み込む
    player = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    //プレイヤーを初期化
    player.initialize(apiKey, this);
}

//関連動画を取得する
private void relateVideoSearch(){
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&type=video&relatedToVideoId=" + videoId
            + "&key=" + apiKey;
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("relatedVideos", response.toString());
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'").create();
            VideoSearchResult result = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoSearchResult.class);
            if(!result.items.isEmpty()){
                for(VideoSearchItems item : result.items){
                    relateVideoIds.add(item.id.videoId);
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", error.toString());
        }
    }));
}

//動画情報を取得するメソッド
private void videoRequest(){
    //Urlを設定
    String searchVideoIds = videoId;
    for(String id: relateVideoIds){
        searchVideoIds += "," + id;
    }
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id="
            + searchVideoIds + "&key=" + apiKey;
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("VideoInfoResponse", response.toString());
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'").create();
            VideoDetail videoDetail = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoDetail.class);
            videoInfo = videoDetail.items.get(0);
            if(!relateVideoIds.isEmpty()){
                for(int i=0; i<videoDetail.items.size(); i++){
                    relateVideoItems.add(videoDetail.items.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", error.toString());
        }
    }));
}

//チャンネル情報を取得するメソッド
private void channelRequest(){
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet,statistics&id="
            + videoInfo.snippet.channelId + "&key=" + apiKey;
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("channelResponse", response.toString());
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'").create();
            ChannelSearchResult result = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ChannelSearchResult.class);
            channelInfo = result.items.get(0);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", error.toString());
        }
    }));
}

//Player関連メソッド
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if(!b){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
    }
}
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue()!=null){
        RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue()!=null){
        RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).stop();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_video_player, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//フラグメントから呼び出せるメソッド
//ゲッターメソッド
@Override
public VideoItems getVideoInfo(){
    return this.videoInfo;
}
@Override
public ChannelSearchItems getChannelInfo(){
    return this.channelInfo;
}
@Override
public List<VideoItems> getRelateVideoItems(){
    return this.relateVideoItems;
}

//プログレスバーを消す
@Override
public void removeProgress(){
    progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

また､このActtivityに遷移する前のFragmentでもVolleyリクエストをしているので､そのソースコードも以下に示します｡ Volleyを管理しているシングルトンクラスも続けて示します｡

**VideoSearchFragment:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson; 
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.dummy.DummyContent;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class VideoSearchFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER

private static final String WOTAGEI = "%E3%83%B2%E3%82%BF%E8%8A%B8%0D%0A";
private static final String WAZAREN = "%e6%8a%80%e9%80%a3%0d%0a";
private static final int POPULAR = 0;
private static final int SKILL = 1;
private static final int TODAY = 0;
private static final int LAST_WEEK = 1;
private static final int LAST_MONTH = 2;
private static final int LATEST = 0;
private static final int ALL = 1;
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * The fragment's ListView/GridView.
 */
private ListView mListView;
private int childPosition;
private int groupPosition;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
private String formatedDate;
private List<VideoItems> showData;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private boolean onLoad;
private View mFooter;
private VideoSearchResult searchResult;


/**
 * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
 * Views.
 */

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
public static VideoSearchFragment newInstance(int childPosition, int groupPosition) {
    VideoSearchFragment fragment = new VideoSearchFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("childPosition", childPosition);
    args.putInt("groupPosition", groupPosition);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public VideoSearchFragment() {
}

//リクエストキュー
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private String apiKey;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
    //mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
    //        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS);

    if(getArguments() != null){
        this.childPosition = getArguments().getInt("childPosition");
        this.groupPosition = getArguments().getInt("groupPosition");
    }

    setRetainInstance(true);

    //情報を取得
    mQueue = RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    apiKey = DeveloperKey.API_KEY;
    showData = new ArrayList<>();

    //デイトフォーマットを初期化
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SS'Z'");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    String url;
    url = getFirstUrl();
    Log.d("url", url);
    //Volleyを使ってHTTP通信GSONでJSONをパース
    if(!url.equals("")) {
        Request(url);
    }

    mFooter = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    mListView.addFooterView(mFooter, null, false);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(view.getContext(), 0, showData, mQueue);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if ((totalItemCount-2 == firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount)&&onLoad) {
                if(searchResult.nextPageToken!=null) {
                    String nextUrl = getNextUrl(searchResult);
                    Request(nextUrl);
                    onLoad=false;
                }else{
                    onLoad=false;
                    mListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //アイテムクリック時の動作を書く動画再生Acticityへ移行｡
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mQueue.stop();
            ListView list = (ListView)parent;
            VideoItems item = (VideoItems)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoPlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(VIDEO_ID, item.id);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private String getFirstUrl() {
    //昨日､1週間､1ヶ月で分ける｡
    String resultUrl="";
    if (this.groupPosition == POPULAR) {
        //PopularVideoを選択した場合
        switch (childPosition) {
            case TODAY:
                formatedDate = sdf.format(TimeCal.addDate(-1).getTime());
                Log.d("date", formatedDate);
                break;
            case LAST_WEEK:
                formatedDate = sdf.format(TimeCal.addDate(-7).getTime());
                Log.d("date2", formatedDate);
                break;
            case LAST_MONTH:
                formatedDate = sdf.format(TimeCal.addMonth(-1).getTime());
                Log.d("date", formatedDate);
                break;
        }
        resultUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + WOTAGEI + "&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&" +
                "order=viewCount&type=video&videoDefinition=high&publishedAfter=" + formatedDate + "&key=" + apiKey;
    }else if(this.groupPosition == SKILL){
        //SkillPracticeを選択したばあい
        switch (childPosition){
            case LATEST:
                formatedDate = sdf.format(TimeCal.addMonth(-1).getTime());
                resultUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + WAZAREN + "&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&" +
                        "order=viewCount&type=video&videoDefinition=high&publishedAfter=" + formatedDate + "&key=" + apiKey;
                break;
            case ALL:
                resultUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + WAZAREN + "&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&" +
                        "type=video&videoDefinition=high&key=" + apiKey;
                break;
        }
    }
    return resultUrl;
}

private String getNextUrl(VideoSearchResult searchResult){
    String pageToken = searchResult.nextPageToken;
    String resultUrl="";
    if (this.groupPosition == POPULAR) {
        //PopularVideoを選択した場合
        resultUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + WOTAGEI + "&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&" +
                "order=viewCount&type=video&videoDefinition=high&pageToken=" + pageToken + "&publishedAfter=" + formatedDate + "&key=" + apiKey;
    }else if(this.groupPosition == SKILL){
        //SkillPracticeを選択したばあい
        switch (childPosition){
            case LATEST:

                resultUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + WAZAREN + "&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&" +
                        "order=viewCount&type=video&videoDefinition=high&pageToken=" + pageToken + "&publishedAfter=" + formatedDate + "&key=" + apiKey;

                break;
            case ALL:
                resultUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + WAZAREN + "&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&" +
                        "type=video&videoDefinition=high&pageToken=" + pageToken + "&key=" + apiKey;
                break;
        }
    }
    return resultUrl;
}


//検索結果を取得するメソッド
private void Request(final String url) {

    RequestSingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,  null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'").create();

            Log.d("response", response.toString());


            searchResult = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoSearchResult.class);

            String videoRequestIds = searchResult.items.get(0).id.videoId;
            for(int i=1; i<searchResult.items.size(); i++){
                videoRequestIds += "," + searchResult.items.get(i).id.videoId;
            }
            String videoRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=" + videoRequestIds + "&key=" + apiKey;
            videoRequest(videoRequestUrl);


            onLoad=true;
            //restoreListPosition();
            //mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            /*
            mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    if ((totalItemCount-2 == firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount)&&onLoad) {
                        if(searchResult.nextPageToken!=null) {
                            String nextUrl = getNextUrl(searchResult);

                            Request(nextUrl);
                            onLoad=false;
                        }else{
                            onLoad=false;
                            mListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            */


            /*
            //アイテムクリック時の動作を書く動画再生Acticityへ移行｡
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ListView list = (ListView)parent;
                    VideoItems item = (VideoItems)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoPlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(VIDEO_ID, item.id);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            */
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("tag", new String(error.networkResponse.data), error);
        }
    }));
}

//動画情報を取得する
public void videoRequest(String url){

    RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'").create();
            final VideoDetail videoDetail = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoDetail.class);
            Log.d("responce", response.toString());
            List<VideoItems> videoList = new ArrayList<VideoItems>();
            for(VideoItems item : videoDetail.items){
                videoList.add(item);
            }
            adapter.addAll(videoList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mQueue!=null){
        RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).stop();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mQueue!=null){
        RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }
}


/**
 * The default content for this Fragment has a TextView that is shown when
 * the list is empty. If you would like to change the text, call this method
 * to supply the text it should use.
 */
public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) {
    View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();

    if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
    }
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
}

}
```

**RequestSingleton:**

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class RequestSingleton {
private static RequestSingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static Context mCtx;

private RequestSingleton(Context context){
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized RequestSingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new RequestSingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
    if(mRequestQueue == null){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public void start(){
    if(mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.start();
    }
}

public void stop(){
    if(mRequestQueue!=null) {
        mRequestQueue.stop();
    }
}

public<T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
}
```

私は､前に発行した`RequestQueue`が､まだ終わらないために新しいリクエストを追加できないのではないかと思うのですがどうでしょうか｡ もし原因がわかるのでしたら教えて下さい｡ よろしくお願いします｡

**追記:**

Volleyのログを出力しました｡しかし､問題のリクエストのログは出ませんでした｡  問題のリクエスト以前のログはでたので､それを貼ります｡

**Volleyログ(問題のリクエストの1つ前):**

```
02-14 21:25:31.146    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika  D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (534  ms) [ ] https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=Mo4A2UnIfIo,C8guOHZ05Gk,ExNqbKb1GEA,9NyjbKBlfWg,HCG56RjlrIc,hGjlBxdjyk4,81ZA2CvNfrU,REvR7ojkpdc,UndmZPxiHz8,YX_OCJmhxrw,N0ebXPPFM-o,bHvBbjHKGus,1S_hksPD-Ts,gVU2vkNVIBQ,lZnxLCU_joQ,YWQwNnq3IY0,EBkNnca1hvA,vm87if2A904,i1GFzAyWMUY,JDY9eyR4Sxg&key={apikey} 0x30b75e1c NORMAL 2
02-14 21:25:31.146    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [ 1] add-to-queue
02-14 21:25:31.147    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+1   ) [77285] cache-queue-take
02-14 21:25:31.147    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [77285] cache-miss
02-14 21:25:31.147    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [77288] network-queue-take
02-14 21:25:31.147    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+391 ) [77288] network-http-complete
02-14 21:25:31.148    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+31  ) [77288] network-parse-complete
02-14 21:25:31.148    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+15  ) [77288] network-cache-written
02-14 21:25:31.148    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [77288] post-response
02-14 21:25:31.149    8243-8243/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika D/Volley﹕ [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+96  ) [ 1] done
```

Comment: 最初のリクエストをした時`W/Settings﹕ Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.`とでるのですがこれは関係ありませんよね｡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リクエストのキャンセル方法が間違っているのだと思います。

`newRequestQueue()`で生成した`RequestQueue`は、アプリケーションが生存している間使いまわすものなので、`stop()`を呼び出す必要自体ないと思われます。

また、`RequestQueue#start()`は`newRequestQueue()`内部で呼び出されますので、自分で呼び出す必要はありません。

他の`Activity`を呼び出す場合など、レスポンスが不要になった場合には、`Request#cancel()`でリクエストをキャンセルします。ただし通信そのものは停止せず、単にレスポンスがハンドリングされなくなるだけという点に注意です。

リクエストを自前で管理して、`Request#cancel()`を呼び出すのは大変なのでタグを使います。

`Activity`ごとにタグを用意して、`Request#setTag()`でタグを付与すれば、その`Activity`に関連付けられた全てのリクエストを、`RequestQueue#cancelAll()`でまとめてキャンセルできます。

#### 公式ドキュメントの記載

[Setting Up a RequestQueue](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html)の記述を読む限りですと、

> If you just need to make a one-time request and don't want to leave the thread pool around, you can create the RequestQueue wherever you need it and call stop() on the RequestQueue once your response or error has come back, using the Volley.newRequestQueue() method described in Sending a Simple Request. But the more common use case is to create the RequestQueue as a singleton to keep it running for the lifetime of your app, as described in the next section.

1度限りの通信で、スレッドプールを残したくない場合、リクエストの度に`RequestQueue`を生成し、このケースではレスポンスもしくはエラーが返却されたら`stop()`を呼び出す必要があると書いてあります。

しかし、より一般的なケースとして、`RequestQueue`をシングルトンとして扱い、アプリケーションのライフサイクル中動作させても構わないというように読めます。

Comment: @quesera2様
試しに､`stop()`と`start()`を取り除いて実行したのですが､解決しませんでした｡

Comment: また､画面遷移時に`cancelAll()`を実行したのですが､直りませんでした｡

Comment: @zousan Volleyはデフォルトだと4つのスレッドプールで運用しますので、それ以上の通信を同時にしない限りはブロックされないです。コードをぱっと見た感じ、API Keyをインスタンス変数に保持する前にリクエスト投げているのが問題のように思えます。

Comment: @quesera様
すみません｡ 実際のコードでは修正したのですが､こっちを修正するのを忘れていました｡しかし､結局このエラーは直りませんでした｡

Comment: @zousan 何らかのエラーが出ているのですか？`adb shell setprop log.tag.Volley VERBOSE`でLogcatにVolleyのログが出せますので、そちらを参照してみるのがいいかもしれません。

Comment: @quesera様
問題のリクエストのログは出ませんでした｡  なので､その直前に行ったリクエストのログを貼りました｡  見た感じ､問題は起こっていないと見えるのですがどうでしょうか｡

Comment: @zousan メソッド自体は呼び出されているのであれば、単にキューが止まっているのかと。`VideoSearchFragment`の`setOnItemClickListener`で`mQueue.stop();`している処理を消す必要があるように思います。

Comment: @quesea様
消して実行したのですが、代わりありませんでした。

Comment: @zousan Volleyのログを見る限り、前回通信は正しく完了しています。Volleyの不都合ではなく、アプリ側の処理の問題になると思いますが、部分的なソースから私が回答することは難しいように思います。今一度、1.start()させたRequestQueueを停止させている処理がないか、2.リクエストするメソッドは本当に呼び出されているのか、という点を確認してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: @quesera2様
ブレークポイントを設置して､デバッグしたのですが､どうも`relateVideoSearch();
    videoRequest();
    channelRequest();`のなかの､各リクエストが終了する前に､次のメソッドを実行しているために､`channelRequest()`で`videoInfo.snippet.channelId`を取得できていないが参照し`NullPointerException`が出ているようでした｡
なのでそれぞれのリクエスト(言い換えると､それぞれのメッソド)が終了してから､次のメソッドを実行するようにすれば直りそうなのですが､そのような方法はありますか?

Comment: @quesera2様
連投すみません｡  原因はわかったので､新しく質問を作らせていただきました｡
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6502/volley%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A4

Answer (score 0):

最近同様の件ではまりました。これとは違っていたらすいません。

- `Activity`の遷移がある
- `RequestQueue`は`singleton`で管理している

この場合、`Activity`の遷移で次のように処理が行われるため、`RequestQueue`が停止状態になります。

1. `Activity A`が`startActivity`
2. `Activity B`が開始。`onStart()`まで実行される
3. その後、`Activity A`の`onStop()`が実行される

なので、`Activity A`の`onStop()`で、本当に`RequestQueue`の`stop()`を呼んでいいか、フラグを用意してチェックする必要があります。

Comment: @fkm様
アドバイス有難うございます｡  しかし､フラグを追加して画面遷移した場合､`stop()`処理をスルーする設定をしたのですがうまくいきませんでした｡