# Volleyリクエストが終わるまで処理を待つ｡

Tags: android, android-volley, android-lifecycle

[Volleyのリクエストが行われない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6474/volley%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)の質問をさせて頂いたものです｡ これの原因はVolleyのリクエストが終了する前に､そのVolleyのリクエストを格納する変数を参照したために､`NullPointerException`が出てしまうというものだとわかりました｡
現在の構成としては､Volleyリクエストを行う`Activity A`､その`Activity A`上で動作する`Fragment A`となっています｡この`Fragment A`で`Activity A`で行われるVolleyリクエストで取得できるデータを取得し､参照しています｡ このデータ取得処理は`Fragment A`の`onActivityCreated()`で行い､そこで､そのリクエストにより得られ､`Activity A`から受け取るであろうデータを参照しています｡  なので､`Fragment A`の`onActivityCreated()`ではまだ`Activity A`のVolleyリクエストが終了していないことがわかります｡  これはデバッグし確認したのでわかりました｡

そこで､`Fragment A`での参照を､`Activity A`でのVolleyリクエスト終了後まで待たせることは可能でしょうか｡  
ちなみに`Fragment A`での参照処理をコメントで括った結果､`Activity A`でのVolleyリクエストは正常に行われ､データも取得出来ていましたので､Volleyリクエストに問題はないとわかりました｡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[volleyのリクエストが行われない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6474/volley%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)の`videoRequest()`を例にしつつ、多分に推測を含むコードになりますが、

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    VideoItems result = handleVideoDetailResponse(response);
    // Fragmentを取得するためのidを設定する
    VideoInfoFragment videoInfoFragment = (VideoInfoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_info_fragment);
    if(videoInfoFragment != null) {
        // Activityから参照できるスコープで、レスポンスを受け取るメソッドを作成する
        videoInfoFragment.showVideoInfo(result);
    }
}
```

`Fragment`の`onActivityCreated()`の時点では、データを取得できていないので、`Activity`から`Fragment`へ取得したデータを渡すメソッドを作る必要があります。

Comment: @quesera2様 要するにFragment側でshowvideoinfoメソッドを作成し、データ取得後に、そのメソッドをアクティビティから呼び出し、showvideoinfoでviewを作成するということですか。

Comment: @zousan はい。そこの連携のやり方はいろいろありますのであくまで上のコードは「レスポンスが返ってきた時点で、Activity 側から Fragment にデータを渡す」の一例となります。

Comment: ありがとう御座います｡  その方針でやってみます｡

Answer (score 1):

Volley のリクエストの結果を onActivityCreated() を参照できるという前提がよくないので
Volley に対するリクエストの結果が返ってきた段階でActivity 側から Fragment に
データを渡してあげましょう。

一般的な話として、Fragment から Activity 側の変数を参照するのは設計として
よくありません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。結果が帰ってきてからデータを渡すことができればいのですが具体的にどう実装すればいいのでしょうか。
すみません。変数を参照するというよりも、取得するという方が正しいです。正確にはフラグメントでインタフェースを定義してそれをアクティビティ側で実装してデータを取得しています。